# Error al ejecutar consulta con ionic desde el movil

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic4

estoy iniciándome con ionic y angular. He hecho una aplicación sencilla donde hago unas consulta sobre una BBDD MySQL y desde el navegador funciona correctamente pero al probar con Devapp la aplicacion me da un error por la consola de VisualStudio, adjunto captura. 
¿A alguiebn que le haya ocurrido?. Por lo que vi es tema del cors pero en teoría lo he habilitado [image: Imagen del error que sale por consola] 
[image: Habilitar cors]

Answer (score 0):

Problema resuelto, mi error es que apuntaba en la aplicación a localhost y debe apuntar a la ip del ordenador en este caso